# Is Ripple's Contract language intended to be Turing complete or sub-Turing complete ?

Tags: ripple, contracts

The wiki seems to imply Turing-completeness because no restrictions on jumps are specified here https://ripple.com/wiki/Contracts#Foundational_Ops.

Which is it and what (if any) is the actual intention ?

Cheers ...

Comment: Cool, I didn't even know Ripple had contracts!

Comment: If the language is Turing complete, they will promptly have to be disabled :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be Turing complete. However, every time a contract is invoked, the maximum number of operations the contract can perform is limited. Operations that access a contract must specify an operation count limit to get a limit higher than the default. Higher limits require higher transaction fees.

Comment: Does the Turing completeness of Ripple allow for denial of service attacks with infinite loops?

Comment: @makerofthings7 No, there's a strict limit on how much work a contract can do.